# In Campaign Tracking, Not update new user in Google Analytics Console?

Tags: android, google-analytics

I have implemented Google Analytics Campaign tracking for our Android App.

Please check this Image

[image]

In the image you can see that New Users showing as zero and sessions showing the count but not update any new user in google analytical console.

What could be the reason for new users not showing the count?

Here is my code please check it.

```
<receiver
    android:name="com.google.android.gms.analytics.AnalyticsReceiver"
    android:enabled="true">
    <intent-filter>
        <action android:name="com.google.android.gms.analytics.ANALYTICS_DISPATCH" />
    </intent-filter>
</receiver>

<service
    android:name="com.google.android.gms.analytics.AnalyticsService"
    android:enabled="true"
    android:exported="false" />

<!--
     Optionally, register CampaignTrackingReceiver and CampaignTrackingService to enable
     installation campaign reporting
-->

<receiver android:name="info.androidhive.googleanalyticsss.app.InstallReceiver"
    android:exported="true">
    <intent-filter>
        <action android:name="com.android.vending.INSTALL_REFERRER" />
    </intent-filter>
</receiver>
<service android:name="com.google.android.gms.analytics.CampaignTrackingService" />
```

BroadcastReceiver receiver code is below :

```
public class InstallReceiver extends BroadcastReceiver {

  @Override
  public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
      try {
          Log.v("ReferralAction", " " + intent.getAction());
          Log.v("ReferralString", " " + intent.getDataString());
          Log.v("referral", " " + intent.toString());
          Log.v("referral", " " + intent.getStringExtra("referrer"));

          String rawReferrer = intent.getStringExtra("referrer");
          String URL = "http://examplepetstore.com/index.html?" + rawReferrer;
          MyApplication.getInstance().trackCampaigns(URL);

      } catch (Exception e) {
          System.out.print(e);
      }

    }
}
```

Send campaign URL to analytics

```
t.send(new HitBuilders.ScreenViewBuilder()
        .setCampaignParamsFromUrl(url)
        .build());
```

Check this URL :

V/Campaign url: http://examplepetstore.com/index.html?utm_source=test_utmsource&utm_medium=test_utmmedium&utm_term=test_utmterm&utm_content=test_utmcontent&utm_campaign=test_utmname

Comment: share you url examle please

Comment: I am also facing the same issue. Couldn't find the solution

Comment: @prakash Please check below answer

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Add this line above trackCampaigns

```
new CampaignTrackingReceiver().onReceive(context, intent);
```

Add receiver in manifest file

```
 <service 
  android:name="com.google.android.gms.analytics.CampaignTrackingService" />
 <receiver
        android:name="com.google.android.gms.analytics.CampaignTrackingReceiver"
        android:enabled="true">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="com.android.vending.INSTALL_REFERRER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </receiver>
```